# Приложение не может подключиться к БД в докер-контейнере

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Все таки у меня получилось сбилдить проект в докере, но при запуске

```
docker-compose up
```

У меня работает все, кроме самого приложения))) Говорит, что не может подключиться к БД. Что я не так сделал?
docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    links:
      - db
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    #environment: 
     # - DATABASE= mysql:db
    #restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    command: python wsgi.py
    depends_on:
      - db

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - app

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql_db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "example"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'mydb'
      MYSQL_USER: 'myuser'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    container_name: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Докер приложения:

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 5000
```

Файл wsgi.py:

```
from myproject import myprojectApp as app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Само подключение в настройках:

```
self.app_db_connect = 'mysql://myuser:password@127.0.0.1:3306/mydb'
```

Файл nginx.conf:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        location/ {
                   include uwsgi_params;
                   uwsgi_pass app:8080;
                  }
       }
```

Comment: `@127.0.0.1:3306` -> `@db:3306`?

Comment: @Exploding Kitten, откуда питон возьмет значение **db**? db - это же контейнер MySQL

Comment: в user network есть dns, по нему оно и поймет какой ip использовать: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge

Comment: а 127.0.0.1 указывает на текущий контейрен (app) в котором никакой базы нет

Comment: @Exploding Kitten, поставил строкой - исчезла ошибка, но выскочила другая: unknow dirrective "location/" in /etc/nginx.conf.d/nginx.conf:3"

Comment: это означает, что у вас есть ошибка в nginx.conf

Comment: @Exploding Kitten, Добавил файл конфигурации nginx. Там же ничего лишнего нет. или я чего-то не дописал?

Comment: скорее всего нужен пробел после location: `location / {`

Comment: @Exploding Kitten, спасибо тебе огромное! Действительно пробел надо было!